# ASP.net Core OData String Key Is Null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata

I have a strange one here. I've been porting some controllers over from asp.net odata to asp.net core odata and ran into a bit of a snag with the primary keys.

In my .net framework 4.6.2 app I have a GUID as a primary key and in the .net core app I have a string as a primary key. I've been able to get most everything working EXCEPT a Get(key) method. This is my method signature:

```
[HttpGet]
[EnableQuery]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromODataUri] string key)
{
    // key is null!
}
```

Comment: Please add your configuration in Startup.cs as well as the model and the controller. I cannot reproduce your issue with the given information...

Answer (score -1):

**Please Below Follow step**

1. Install Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData from NuGet Package
2. StartUp.cs

   ```
      public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
      {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        services.AddOData(); //This Is added for OData
      }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
       if (env.IsDevelopment())
       {
           app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
       }
       else
       {
           app.UseHsts();
       }

       app.UseHttpsRedirection();
       app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
       {
           routeBuilder.EnableDependencyInjection(); //This Is added for OData
           routeBuilder.Expand().Select().Count().OrderBy().Filter(); //This Is added for OData
       });
   }
   ```
3. In Api Conteroller

   ```
   [HttpGet]
   [EnableQuery] //This Is added for OData
   public ActionResult<List<TestModel>> Get()
   {
       var model = new List<TestModel>();
       for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
       {
           var res = new TestModel()
           {
               ID = i,
               Name="Test"+i,
               Mobile="Test"+i,
               City="Test_"+i
           };
           model.Add(res);
       }
       return model;
   }
   public class TestModel
   {
       public int ID { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public string Mobile { get; set; }
       public string City { get; set; }
   }
   ```
4. After Run Api And Check Like This
   [image]